# How to send Excel document to the printer in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, excel, phpexcel

I created *Excel* document with `phpexcel` library. But I could not printed with printer. How can I send this document to printer with `phpexcel` or PHP or JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: You can't. All you do with PHPExcel is to actually write a file to the File-System. Sending a Print-Request to the printer needs to be done by excel and thus by the user himself.

Comment: Can I open excel file client side with php ? this for preparing send to printer .

Comment: Client Side? Your PHP is executed on your Server, so: No, absolutely no way.

Comment: Well, Is possible with jquery , javascript  ?

Comment: Maximum you can do is printing the current web page - but no file from the file system as JS in the browser (luckily) can not access it.

Comment: Thank Charminbear all your answer. Just one question to you. How can print on bill which have different size ? When I print with html absolute div It 's not to be correct. It slipped always. It's my best solution with excel. Do you have any Idea for that?

Comment: Uff, sorry, I´m no frontend-developer, so I don't really know about printing HTML. You probably need some special CSS just for the print, but maybe google a tutorial for this or something.